# Strange compiler errors

Tags: objective-c

I am working on a project and 'suddenly' the compiler gives errors on this bit of code:

```
__weak typeof(self) selfRef = self;
[self.beaconConnection checkFirmwareUpdateWithCompletion:^(ESTFirmwareInfoVO *result, NSError *error) {
    if(error != nil){
        NSLog(@"Could not get firmware info: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    } else {
        if(result.isUpdateAvailable){
            [[selfRef updateFirmwareBttn] setEnabled:true];
            [[selfRef updateFirmwareBttn] setTitle:result.firmwareVersion forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        } else {
            [[selfRef updateFirmwareBttn] setEnabled:false];
        }
    }
}];
```

The problem is the second line, and the error:

> DOBeaconViewController.m:123:64: Expected ')'

It also gives:

> DOBeaconViewController.m:123:62: Type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'

and:

> DOBeaconViewController.m:123:62: Incompatible block pointer types sending 'int ((^)(void))' to parameter of type 'ESTObjectCompletionBlock' (aka 'void (^)(__strong id, NSError *__strong)')

There are set of errors after that, but that is because the error in the declaration.

So the bracket is there... and I haven't made a change to this part of the code for months.

I tried cleaning the project, rebuilding it, but it gives this error all the time, and I have no idea why. I did a view successful builds earlier today, but then tried to compile with bit code on (but had to turn it off again as one of my frameworks doesn't contain bit code yet). Since then I get this error.

What could I try to resolve it? I just not understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that for some reason the header defining ESTFirmwareInfoVO (which is part of the framework) was not loaded.

Adding specifically

```
#import <EstimoteSDK/ESTFirmwareInfoVO.h>
```

solved it.